# Do the powers in Heroes manifest only once a generation?

Tags: heroes

I just started watching Season 2. Claire and Takedo Kensei can both heal. West and Nathan Petrelli can both fly. So does a power manifest only once within a generation?

Comment: How do you define _'a generation'?_ Takezo Kensei lived ~400 years ago.

Comment: True. But the difference between West and Nathan is just a generation.

Answer (score 4):

The complicated dynamics of who gets what powers is never fully explained.  For example, Nathan was the son of two people with powers, but was born without powers, they were granted to him synthetically.  Peter's powers, however, came to him naturally.  Peter has a variation of his dad's powers.

Claire's powers are also interesting to note.  Her mom (and we also find her uncle) can control fire.  Her father, Nathan, was synthetically given powers.  She was born with the ability to heal quickly.

The only person that has a clear line of inheritance that I can recall is Syler, since his real father was exactly like him.

Comment: @ChetterHummin so I inadverdantly answered your question.  Yes, the same powers can happen within the same generation.  Claire's mom and uncle both had the same power, albeit their fires were different color.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Mendez]   [image: Usutu]

- [**Isaac Mendez**](http://heroeswiki.com/Isaac_Mendez) and [**Usutu**](http://heroeswiki.com/Usutu) could both ***paint the future***.

[image: Meredith]   [image: Flint]

- [**Meredith Gordon**](http://heroeswiki.com/Meredith_Gordon) and her brother [**Flint**](http://heroeswiki.com/Flint_Gordon,_Jr.) could both ***create and manipulate fire***.

[image: Linderman]  [image: Ishi]

- [**Daniel Linderman**](http://heroeswiki.com/Daniel_Linderman) and [**Ishi Nakamura**](http://heroeswiki.com/Ishi_Nakamura) could both ***heal others through physical contact***.

  *(Ishi Nakamura died in the early 1990s and is therefore only seen in flashbacks, which is why she doesn't look the same age as Daniel Linderman, even though they are arguably the same generation)*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just finished season 2. Hope to see these characters soon!